# Seaborn Heatmap Not Placing Data on Axes Properly

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm new to using Seaborn and usually only use Matplotlib.pyplot.

With the recent COVID developments I was asked by a supervisor to put together estimates of how changes to the student population & expenses we need to fund affected student fees (I work in a college budgeting office). I've been able to put together my scenario analysis, but am now trying to visualize these results in a heatmap.

What I'd like to be able to do is have the:

```
 x-axis be my population change rates,
 y_axis be my expense change rates,
 cmap be my new student fees depending on the x & y axis.
```

What my code is currently doing is:

```
 x-axis is displaying the new student fee category (not sure how to describe this - see picture)
 y-axis is displaying the population change and expense change (population, expenses)
 cmap is displaying accurately
```

Essentially, my code is stacking each scenario on top of the others along the y-axis.

Here is a picture of what is currently being produced, which is not correct:

[image: Example Output - NOT Correct]

I've attached a link to a [Colab Jupyter notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PlUTE94rgANMJbQHUmgUKciJlPpq-9fw) with my code, and below is a snippet of the section giving me problems.

```
# Create Pandas DF of Scenario Analysis       
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Pop, Exp, NewStud, NewTotal)), 
                  index = [i for i in range(0,len(NewStud))], 
                  columns=['Population_Change', 'Expense_Change', 'New_Student_Activity_Fee', 'New_Total_Fee'])

# Group this scenario analysis 
df = df.groupby(['Population_Change', 'Expense_Change'], sort=False).max()

# Create Figure 
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
ax = plt.subplot(111)

# Drop New Student Activity Fee Column. Analyze Only New Total Fee
df = df.drop(['New_Student_Activity_Fee'], axis=1)

########################### Not Working As Desired
sb.heatmap(df)
###########################
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DataFrame is not in the right shape for `seaborn.heatmap()`. For example, as a result of the `groupby` operation, you have `Population_Change` and `Expense_Change` as a MultiIndex, which would only be used for labelling by the plotting function.

So instead of the `groupby`, first drop the superfluous column, and then do this:

```
df = df.pivot(index='Expense_Change', columns='Population_Change', values='New_Total_Fee')
```

Then `seaborn.heatmap(df)` should work as expected.